# Default sourceSets in Android Studio 0.6.0

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

My understanding is that if you create a `java` folder in any flavor it is detected automatically as a source set. This works perfectly for my first flavor. However, it fails for my second flavor (i.e. the `java` folder doesn't turn blue). Any one know why this happens?

Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bbct.android.common"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("codeguru.keystore")
            keyAlias "codeguru"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        lite {
            applicationId "bbct.android"
        }
        premium {
            applicationId "bbct.android.premium"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0'
    liteCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile 'com.jayway.android.robotium:robotium-solo:5.1'
}
```

Comment: mine doesn't turn blue as well. There seem to be some random stuff going on. Same for the assets folder. Anyway it does not create any issue for me. Have you experienced trouble?

Comment: @WarrenFaith The problem is that autocompletion, reorganize imports, and any other feature that works with source code is broken for that flavor.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't realized that as I have no java file there. Anyway I just copy&pasted a java file there and it was at least recognized as a java file. Autocompletion started to work with that one but not with a new created file... very odd. You should file a bug report!

Comment: @WarrenFaith Seems to be working as designed. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69257&q=android%20studio%20flavor&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

According to this issue, the source folders in only the currently selected flavor will be recognized.

Comment: I do agree that this kind of selection based highlight is a bad solution. In my experience switching flavors is already pretty slow...

Comment: @WarrenFaith It makes sense now that I see how it works. You probably don't want to autocomplete class names, methed names, etc. from a different flavor than the one you are currently working on.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the flavor to gradle inside `android{...}`:

```
productFlavors{

  yourFirstFlavorFolderName{
  }

  yourSecondFlavorFolderName{
  }
}
```

Then you will need to `Sync Your Files With Gradle` and possibly `Synchronize` your project. If this doesn't work you can check your `.iml` file, look for the new added flavor, and make sure there is a line similar to this:

```
<sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src/yourSecondFlavorName/java" isTestSource="false" />
```

Comment: I have the productFlavors declared in my build.gradle file already.

Comment: There is no such line in my .iml file. That seems to be the reason that Android Studio doesn't behave the way I want it to. Now I wonder why gradle didn't generate that line for me?

Comment: I really do not know why gradle didn't do it. You can try starting a blank project and see if gralde behaves properly there...